# parquet streaming of Azure Blob storage into databricks with unity catalog

Tags: pyspark, azure-blob-storage, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

Unity Catalog have recently been set up in my databricks account, and I am trying to stream from an Azure container containing parquet files to a service catalog, using a notebook that ran before.

I do however now get the following

```
py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.format(java.lang.String) is not whitelisted on class class org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader
```

when trying to run the following spark command from my Notebook:

```
df = (spark
      .readStream
      .format("cloudFiles")
      .option("cloudFiles.format", "parquet")
      .option("cloudFiles.useNotifications", "false") # useNotifications determines if we efficiently scan the new files or if we set up a subscription to listen to new file events
      .option("cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode", "failOnNewColumns") # schemaEvolutionMode determines what happens when the schema changes
      .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", schemaPath)
      .load(dataPath)
     )
```

where `schemaPath`and `dataPath` contain the paths to the parquet schema and data files.

The closest related error I have found is the following pre-Unity Catalog error, suggesting that I should disable table access control on my clusters:

https://kb.databricks.com/en_US/streaming/readstream-is-not-whitelisted

All table access control are disabled in my Admin Console.

Are there some other settings that should be set to ensure white-listing from Azure files now that Unity Catalog is set up?

------ Edit -----

Using a Single User cluster on Databricks runtime version 11.3 beta, I get the following error instead:

```
com.databricks.sql.cloudfiles.errors.CloudFilesIOException: Failed to write to the schema log at location
```

followed by the location to the azure schema in my storage location. I also get this error message by spawning new job clusters from azure datafactory.

Comment: what is Databricks Runtime version? Are you using shared cluster?

Comment: I tried with a few different clusters. Currently I have a shared cluster with 11.3 beta runtime version. I have tried with single user cluster and runtime versions 11.1 and 11.2 as well - but still get the same error message. I will try to isolate the problem a bit more